# Reactjs clicking on button doesnt work after adding webpack and babel to my project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Before adding webpack this worked, after adding it it stop works.

```
export class Main extends Component { 
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                currentPage: states.allProducts
            };
           
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            let currentPage = this.state.currentPage;
        }
       
        handleClick() {
            alert('a');
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Say hello
                </button>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the message key in the state object?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use create-react-app.
It will set up and installing all babel plugins and presets by its own, so you don't face such an issue.

As mentioned here [How To Use Async Await in React](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/#how-to-use-async-await-in-react-using-the-asyncawait-syntax)

> Now, create-react-app supports async/await out of the box. But if you have a webpack boilerplate you may hit an error (more in a minute).

it is because lack of some babel plugins, you can install them, and hopefully, everything will work fine again

Comment: but what if I want to change the webpack. config, is it possible?

Comment: yes, but you must also install other packages such as cra-webpack-config, [medium article for set up](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc)